# How to make an app to display YouTube subscriber count on windows desktop

Tags: windows, youtube, counter, desktop

i am looking for a code to build an app to run on my windows desktop to find the list of my YouTube channel subscribers. it has to update the YouTube counter dynamically just like the web version of YouTube channel count.i recommend java as a source code. if there is any script to get data from web and display on windows desktop using java then i'd like to know.

Comment: In general, software engineering is as much about writing original code as it is about finding existing libraries. Unfortunately, library recommendation requests are off-topic here. You can either use a search engine, or decide if it is easier just to build what you need - using the API should not be too onerous.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Youtube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

There are lots of sample code that you can probably copy + paste to get a feel for